# mapproxy.config - WARNING - unknow 'html' in sources

Tags: python, wms, tiles, cache, mapproxy

mapproxy.config - WARNING - unknow 'html' in sources.gasps_osm_source has thrown by terminal
when i run : mapproxy-seed -c 16 --continue -f mapproxy.yaml -s seed.yaml , and no one tile has been cashed... o tiles.

```
settings:

services:
  demo:
  tms:
    use_grid_names: true
    origin: 'nw'
  kml:
      use_grid_names: true
  wmts:
    # use restful access to WMTS
    restful: true
    # this is the default template for MapProxy
    restful_template: '/{Layer}/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileCol}/{TileRow}.{Format}'
    # and also allow KVP requests
    kvp: true
  wms:
    md:
      title: MapProxy WMS Proxy
      abstract: This is a minimal MapProxy example.

layers:
  - name: osm_background
    title: osm_background
    sources: [gasps_osm_cache]

caches:
  gasps_osm_cache:
    grids: [osm_grid]
    sources: [gasps_osm_source]
    meta_size: [6, 6]
    meta_buffer: 100

sources:
  gasps_osm_source:
    type: wms
    html:
      client_timeout: 500
    req:
      url: 'http://xxx.local:8080/geoserver/test_osm/wms'
      layers: osm:osm_layerset  
    coverage:

      srs: 'EPSG:3857'
grids:
    osm_grid:
        base: GLOBAL_MERCATOR
        srs: 'EPSG:3857'
        origin: nw

globals:
```

and

```
seeds:
  myseed1:
    caches: [gasps_osm_cache]
    # grids: []
    #coverages: [changed_area]
    levels:
      to: 12
    refresh_before:
      time: 2019-9-25T12:35:00
```

[image]

Comment: Is your GeoServer for sure running on local:8080 and not on localhost:8080?

Comment: @user30184 Yes, I sure that it is ```xxx.local:8080/geoserver/web/``` not ```localhost```

Comment: Then I suggest to have a look at the logs of your GeoServer and check what kind of wrong request it is receiving from your MapProxy. You may need to raise the logging level into GEOTOOLS_DEVELOPER.

Comment: @user30184 some more info, if I change url config from real to ```url:`asfasdasdewghrwgsdfds` ``` for example it is  give same result: mapproxy.config - WARNING - unknow 'html' in sources

Comment: I guess it is just a warning about having an unsupported element in the configuration. https://mapproxy.org/docs/1.11.0/sources.html does not mention "html".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some problem with my eyes will be

```
http:
```

not

```
html:
```

Thanks to gislab members and @user30184